# Nhibernate doesn't save hasManyToMany data

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here are my mappings for `Complex` and `Dish` :

```
    public class ComplexMapping:ClassMap<Complex>
    {
        public ComplexMapping()
        {
            Table("ComplexTable");

            Id(comp => comp.Id,"ComplexId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(comp => comp.Name,"Name").Not.Nullable();
            Map(comp => comp.Subscribe, "DescriptionComplex");

            HasManyToMany(comp => comp.ScrollOfDish)
              .Table("ComplexDish")
              .ParentKeyColumn("ComplexId")
              .ChildKeyColumn("DishId").Cascade.All();

        }
    }

    public class DishMapping:ClassMap<Dish>
    {
        public DishMapping()
        {
            Table("DishTable");

            Id(dish => dish.Id, "DishId").GeneratedBy.Identity();

            Map(dish => dish.Name);
            Map(dish => dish.Description);
            Map(dish => dish.Price);

            References(x => x.Category, "CategoryId").Cascade.None();

            HasManyToMany(comp => comp.Scroll)
                 .Table("ComplexDish")
                 .ParentKeyColumn("DishId")
                 .ChildKeyColumn("ComplexId").Inverse();

        }
    }
```

I use DAO pattern - and when data from front-end come I create needed object

[image]

And object save but not whole object only name and description have saved but collection of products doesn't save. I think i forgot some simple thing please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a many-to-many to me represents associations between two separate entities where the entities themselves manage their life cycles.

For example. In your scenario

```
var firstDish = new Dish();
var secondDish = new Dish();

// 01 -- both dish objects are now attached to the session
session.SaveOrUpdate(firstDish);
session.SaveOrUpdate(secondDish);


var firstComplexObject = new Complex();
firstComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(firstDish);
firstComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(secondDish);

// 02 -- first Complex Object now attached to the session
session.SaveOrUpdate(firstComplextObject);

var secondComplexObject = new Complex();
secondComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(firstDish);
secondComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(secondDish);

// 03 -- second Complex Object now attached to the session
session.SaveOrUpdate(secondComplextObject);
```

I would avoid the complex Object managing the life cycle of Dish object like

```
var firstDish = new Dish();
var secondDish = new Dish();

var firstComplexObject = new Complex();
firstComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(firstDish);
firstComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(secondDish);


// the dish object are not attached to session 
// hence the NHibernate has to save the entire object graph here!!!!
// 01 -- first Complex Object now attached to the session
session.SaveOrUpdate(firstComplextObject);

var secondComplexObject = new Complex();
secondComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(firstDish);
secondComplexObject.ScrollOfDish.Add(secondDish);

// 02 -- second Complex Object now attached to the session
session.SaveOrUpdate(secondComplextObject);
```

Also since dishes would certainly be shared between two complex object, it would make sense to not cascade a DELETE from the complex item to the dish.

Hence I would make sure that you DO manage the life cycles separately.
Hope this pushes you  in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem was in this area and i have fixed it with your help!)